# How to add Angular Material for .Net Core 2.1 Project through Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am learning angular and now I am doing some POC to include angular material into my .Net Core 2.1 Project. So is there any tutorial to install angular material to the .Net Core 2.1 Project. I've tried many posts but they are with respective VS Code. I thought this might different wrt VS 17.

Could anyone give me step by step tutorial for the installation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you do that with `npm install`. Angular material has nothing to do with visual studio. You can open a command prompt chage directory to the root of your angular application and use the install command there. And you are done

Comment: Yes @Manish. I've got it

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. 
After some decent search through internet. I found this post :https://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-angular-6-material-angular-6-asp-net-core-app/ which helped me install the angular material.

But, we need to match the `@angular/cdk` & `@angular/material`versions to `@angular/core` if your getting compilation errors.